# Why does the use of multiple filters create vignetting?

Tags: lens, filters, polarizer, vignetting

Recently I have had vignetting problem with my Sigma 18-200mm f/3.5-6.3 DC OS HSM (72mm)

After checking, it is specified in the manual that one should not use multiple filters or thick filter (as polarizing filter) on the lens because it might create vignetting.

I have indeed used very often a polarizing filter and UV filter, some time together.

Is it common for lenses to be sensitive to the number of filter attached? or is this only this model which has a weak spot?

Comment: Not an answer to the question you're asking, but: why are you using a UV filter?

Comment: @Philip Kendall Hearing contradictory claims about UV exiting or not the sensor, I gave it a try

Comment: With digital cameras, UV filters are entirely unnecessary. The sensor is not sensitive to UV. You don't need one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any wide angle lens will have problems with multiple filters, simply because the edge of the filters will start to encroach on the corners of the image formed.